# Big Trailer effects

Tags: effects

Hi

I'm doing a trailer for an action/thriller film and I need to make some of those big boomy sounds that they use to emphasise picture cuts. Does anyone know where I could start with making these effects?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Virtually any subtractive synth with an LFO.  Get a sound that is close to what you want and then start tweaking.

Answer (score 1):

Modify and tweak large metal impacts, layer then with synth material etc.
Basically anything with a clear transient and impact and ideally recorded at high resolution will be useful source material - just start thinking big and boom and layer everything up :)

Comment: Garage doors make a great base layer for these kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

Just before we switched from an oil fired boiler to gas, I recorded the 1200 liters oil tank, hitting its side. 
It made an extremely low, and eerie deep tone.
Back in protools I cut some of mids and added some Altiverb reverb, and made a send to a DBX120a.
It had the lows and a naturalness that I found nice.

I could send an example if you want to?

Best wishes,

Mikkel

Comment: thanks mikkel, it would be great to hear an example. unfortunately, we have gas heating but i'm sure i could find a big water tank somewhere. my email is phobic4king@hotmail.co.uk

Comment: thanks everyone, some great ideas here that i'll try out.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with a 40 hz sine tone, add reverb and send it to the sub. Try slowing it down using vari-fi. You can also use explosions, pitch them down an octave or two and add reverb. You could use a reverse explosion for the beginning of the sound. You could also use an electronic bass drum sound like a 909 or an 808 to trigger the reverb.